# Why do i get no suitable driver found error in my Kotlin MySQL app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mysql-connector

I am trying to use mysql data in my basic Kotlin app and i use Android Studio. I've retrieved data and printed them into console with running only "Test.kt" file. But i want to use it in textView and stuff.

[test.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9kbu.png)

When i want to run whole app,  i'm facing "No suitable driver found" error.

[MainActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pfo2.png)

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.dbtest

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var list = ArrayList<DataModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener {

            list = DBCon.connection()

            for (i in 0 until list.size){
                if (i == list.size){
                    textView.text = list[list.size].firstName + list[list.size].lastName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DBCon.kt**

```
package com.example.dbtest

import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException

object DBCon {

    @JvmStatic
    fun connection(): ArrayList<DataModel> {

        var list = ArrayList<DataModel>()

        try {
            val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb",
                "root",
                ""
            )

            val statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)
            val result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` FROM `testtable`")

            while (result.next()){

                list.add(DataModel(result.getInt("id"), result.getString("firstName"),result.getString("lastName")))

            }

        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return list
    }
}
```

**Test.kt**

```
package com.example.dbtest

fun main(){

    var list = ArrayList<DataModel>()
    list = DBCon.connection()

    for (i in 0 until list.size){
        println(list[i].id.toString() + "- " + list[i].firstName + " " + list[i].lastName)
    }

}
```

**DataModel.kt**

```
package com.example.dbtest

data class DataModel(val id: Int, val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

I'm new to Kotlin and i learned a lot new things to figure this out but i couldn't. Please lead my way to work this out. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Here is some things i did based on my search in order to solve this:

- added jar file -> mysql-connector-java-8.0.21 and used as library // Done already
- tried to add -> Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") // Not worked
- tried to add -> Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") // Not worked
- added permission -> "android.permission.INTERNET" // Not worked
- even tried to use -> AsyncTask // Not worked

Comment: JDBC is not a suitable solution for Android apps. JDBC is not built for unreliable Internet connections. It also requires you to make your database publicly accessible and bake login credentials into your app, which is a security problem. Please consider doing something else, such as having a Web service handle your database I/O securely, with your app talking to the Web service.

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J 8.0 library cannot be used on Android because it relies on Java classes and features not available on Android.

Comment: The fact that it can work on single kt file but can't work as whole app made suspicious and think i was doing something wrong. Now i know why it is and what to do next, thank you @CommonsWare !!